# How to search inside of Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, uisearchbar

In my `UITableView` I have cells with avatar image and name surname(UIImage and Label). And I want to search inside of my `UITableView`. So, when I type my user's name or surname it would show user's name surname with the avatar image.

Now, I can search just inside of an array with the next code:

```
var rosters = [String: UIImage]()
var displayNames = [String]()
var filteredTableData = [String]()

// Here I remove all elements from the array and add to it user display name and avatar
rosters.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
for user in OneRoster.buddyList.fetchedObjects! {
  var roster = OneRoster.userFromRosterForJID(jid: user.jidStr)
  var image = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppvCardAvatarModule?.photoDataForJID(roster?.jid)

  rosters[user.displayName] = UIImage(data: image!)!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> onlineUserCell {
    let cell:onlineUserCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! onlineUserCell

    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
      cell.username.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
      //cell.avatarImage.image = images[indexPath.row]

      return cell
    }
}


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        displayNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

        for (name, image) in rosters {
            displayNames.append(name)

            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
            let array = (displayNames as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
            filteredTableData = array as! [String]
        }

        let array = (displayNames as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        filteredTableData = array as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

So, this code searches just among name surname, without avatar image. I thought, that I can use dictionary, as:

```
var users = [UIImage: String]()
```

and later search by String and show as `UIImage` and String together in the cell. But I searched a lot and couldn't found how to search, that later I can search by String and to get result with `UIImage`, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should not really use multiple arrays to hold the data, it will get confusing quite fast, create a struct or class to hold the name and the corresponding image. then use swift `filter` to search / filter the array of custom objects.

Answer (score 3):

Searching the dictionary could be done by just accessing the values from the dictionary and searching them like

```
var users = [UIImage: String]()
let values = Array(users.values)
```

However this use of dictionary seems a bit wrong as you will never look up a value based on the UIImage I guess.

What you should use instead then would be a tuple or a class that holds both UIImage and String

```
var users = [(image:UIImage,name:String)]()
```

you can then simply filter the values like

```
users.filter { (element:(image:UIImage, name:String)) -> Bool in
    return element.name.containsString(searchfrase)
}
```

Comment: I get an error: `Instance member 'users' cannot be used on type 'TableViewController'`

Comment: I need more info than that to figure out what you are doing.

Comment: what else can I tell you? Just ask me, please

Comment: Which of my suggested solutions did you try and what does your code look like when using it?